# Different parents for new Winform with a single constructor

Tags: c#, winforms

Im running into a bit of an issue regarding Children and parents.

I have 2 forms which have the same dropdown menus, both of which have the ability to add additional options to them. When the "(add new)" option is selected in any of the combo boxes my third form is loaded which enables the addition of a new option.

This is the code for that third window (as it stands)

```
 public partial class taskNewDropdownEntry : Form
{
    taskWindow _owner;
    applianceWindow _owner2;
    int windowType;
    int manufacturer_id;
    sqlMod data = new sqlMod();
    public int setManufacturerID {get { return manufacturer_id; } set { manufacturer_id = value; } }


    public taskNewDropdownEntry(taskWindow owner, int type)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._owner = owner;
        this.windowType = type;

    }

    public taskNewDropdownEntry(applianceWindow owner, int type)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._owner2 = owner;
        this.windowType = type;
    }

    private void taskNewDropdownEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (windowType == 1)
        {
            instructionLabel.Text = "Input the new appliance type below";

        }
        else if (windowType == 2)
        {
            instructionLabel.Text = "Input the new manufacturer below";

        }
        else if (windowType == 3)
        {
            instructionLabel.Text = "Input the new model below";

        }


    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (windowType == 1)
        {
            data.insertApplianceType(textField.Text);
            _owner.refreshTypeCombo();
        }
        else if (windowType == 2)
        {
            data.insertManufacturerSimple(textField.Text);
            _owner.refreshManuCombo();
        }
        else if (windowType == 3)
        {
            data.insertModelSimple(manufacturer_id, textField.Text);
            _owner.refreshModelCombo();
        }
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Now, my issue is that the 2 forms that call this third form are different - thus my only thought of how to solve this would be to duplicate some of the code and modify the methods (you can see the second constructor already added).

Instead of having multiple constructors, and duplicated methods (in this class, or in a seperate one) is there a way whereby I can use the same constructor but different owners depending on the form that calls it?

Comment: How does the body of this question relate to the title?

Comment: Im far from understanding the problem, its not very clear described, anyway, take a look at naming convention of C#... also its not a good practice to keep parent reference in a form, think about a different design at best, you can use events of the child form like Closing, Closed

Comment: its a form that calls another form, and the parent reference is needed to refresh the controls on the parent form once the child is finished. How is this not good practice? The problem is that I don't want to have to write another constructor for each potential parent that might need to use the form above as a child. I want the `owner` variable to be able to refrence ANY parent, not just the specific one as demonstrated above

Comment: ok, check the answer, I got it from the code somehow, typical why-do-we-need-interfaces-or-inheritance issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too much implementation in your child form. The way I would tackle this is to

Add a property to your child form:

```
public string InstructionLabel { get; set; }
```

This allows your parent forms to individually set the label text when instantiating the form, and also set up an event handler for when the form is closing. So your parent form would have code something like

```
var newItemForm = new taskNewDropdownEntry();
newItemForm.InstructionLabel = "Input the new appliance type below";
newItemForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(ChildFormClosing);
```

Then somewhere early in your child form's life cycle (FormLoading event) set

```
instructionLabel.Text = InstructionLabel;
```

Then also add a property in the child form for

```
public string NewItem { get; set; }
```

your child form should set this public property in the `btnOK_Click` event

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.NewItem =textField.Text;
}
```

Then your parent form listens for a `FormClosing` event, and when it hits that event it takes the `NewItem` text, adds it to the relevant combo and refreshes it. So in the parent form, the handler looks like

```
private void ChildFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    sqlMod data = new sqlMod();
    data.insertApplianceType(textField.Text);
    refreshTypeCombo();
}
```

Comment: so something like `this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);` ?

Comment: I updated with an example, but don't use Form*Closed* (as the form would be closed at that point), use Form*Closing* (which is triggered just prior to it closing). If you used *Closed* it would be too late to pull back properties from the child form.

Comment: I see what you mean, and i like your answer. However, this now means im duplicating all my insert and refresh code into each potential parent - the main reason for me having it contained within this class was to avoid just that.

Comment: So while currently it is only 2 windows that use this, in the future it could be far more than that. It seemed better to include said code so as to avoid that duplication.

Comment: This way each parent has a clean implementation of what label text to display, and which data is updated. You could push the data updating into the child form (and use interfaces to keep it generic), but as it's only a single line of code at the moment, I would say it's cleaner and easier to read if that logic is in the parent form.

Comment: i should have mentioned, each parent can submit a value 1-3, so handling it within the child made more sense

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. In that case, just use FormClosing event handler to refresh the combo in the parent. You can keep your code as it stands, but you wouldn't need to pass 'owner' to the child form.

Comment: You arent wrong @mikus, but paul explained things better. I have upvoted your answer as it was correct, but less detailed than this one.

Comment: sure, no problem, although its the interface that solves the original problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to understand the question but code speaks for all. 
There are 2 options, worse (because keeping the parent reference is not a good practice first of all):

1. create an interface that both classes `taskWindow` and `applianceWindow` (where is the naming convention for god's sake!) implement, ex

   intrerface IRefreshable {
        void refreshManuCombo();
   }

then constructor and your poperty can have type of IRefreshable

```
IRefreshable _owner;
public taskNewDropdownEntry(IRefreshable owner, int type)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this._owner = owner;
}
```

2. better option, use child form events like Closed to implement refreshing logic in parent. You just need to register event handler before showing the form and voila. Check examples here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed(v=vs.110).aspx

You can also implement your own public form event for more custom usage (ex. DataChanged, ResultGenerated).

Comment: I dont understand what is wrong with my window naming... `taskWindow` is the window that has the task, `applianceWindow` holds appliance information.

Comment: Check this, especially class names: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx 
Your forms are classes, types

Comment: I understand. I was never taught the difference, but will remember this in the future. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll attempt to implement your solution above now.

Comment: keeping the convention makes it much more readable for others. It's easier when you know what is a class, what is a field, etc.. without checking the definition :)